# jquery, change css class of parent td

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

i have table that looks like this:

```
<table class="content">
<tbody>
   <tr class="fc-first">

      <td class="fc-widget-content fc-day0 fc-first">
    <div>
        <div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
        <div class="fc-day-content">
            <div style="position:relative"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      </td>
      <td class="fc-widget-content fc-day1">
    <div>
        <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
        <div class="fc-day-content">
            <div style="position:relative"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      </td>
      <td class="fc-widget-content fc-day2">
    <div>
        <div class="fc-day-number">3</div>
        <div class="fc-day-content">
            <div style="position:relative"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="fc-week1"></tr>
   <tr class="fc-week2"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and i want  to add CSS class to `td` based only what contains `<div> class"fc-day-number">2</div>`  my jquery code so far:

```
var content_td;
var content = $('.content' );
content_td = content.find('td');
```

i thought i can use nested find but dont know how.

Comment: Lots of issues here.  Your <td> and <tr> tags are not closed and `$(.content)` should be `$('.content')`. Would recommend fixing this up first.

Comment: @PassKit actually are fine, it's a typo: replace `</tr>` with `</td>` where needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the `.closest()` method

```
$('table.content td[class="fc-day-number"]').closest('td').addClass('SOME_CLASS');
```

and your fixed HTML

```
<table class="content">
<tbody>

   <tr class="fc-first">

    <td class="fc-widget-content fc-day0 fc-first">
      <div>
        <div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
        <div class="fc-day-content">
            <div style="position:relative"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="fc-widget-content fc-day1">
      <div>
        <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
        <div class="fc-day-content">
            <div style="position:relative"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="fc-widget-content fc-day2">
      <div>
        <div class="fc-day-number">3</div>
        <div class="fc-day-content">
            <div style="position:relative"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

   </tr>

   <tr class="fc-week1"></tr>
   <tr class="fc-week2"></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you quote the class selector, to make it a String literal.  Also, make content_td a variable.

```
var content = $(".content"); //Quotes added
var content_td = content.find('td');
```